# Can I receive a javascript alert from another PHP page? If yes, how?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is it possible to receive a JavaScript alert on the *`index.php`*  while running another code on another page like *`second.php`* ?

**Example :**

I have the following form, Submitting data to another file :

this code is in the index.php page :

```
<form method="POST" action="./update.php">
<input type="text" class="main-link" name="link" id="link" value="'.$user_db['values_text'].'" placeholder="Set text new">
<input type="submit" class="main-link-check" href="#" value="Set">
</form>';
```

And on second page update.php :

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
var str2 = "DEFG";
if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
alert(str2 + " found");
}
</script>';
```

When I submit some text , I do not receive any alerts. How can i fix it?

Comment: You'd have to ajax it to your page and then run the script. This won't work through a form like this.

Comment: @wateriswet, do you have the simplest ajax code that will solve my issue or a guide ?

Comment: `action="./update.php"` check this action/path is correct ?

Comment: @AkhileshSingh yes the path is correct because i have another running code updating the db that works fine

Comment: are you sure that update.php reaches the part where it should echo the alert? maybe you have some conditions (or errors) that prevent this. Have you looked with developer tools/firebug or similar at what the server sends to your browser after you click on submit?

Comment: also, a href attribute on a submit element is strange...I think it will be ignored, but not sure if it might have undesired effects in some browser

Comment: Yes this should work if it is your echo statement is reached after submit.Ensure your `action="./update.php"` refers to the file correctly according to location.

Comment: why you have a `href="#"` on an `<input type="submit"`?

Comment: @techie_28 i didn't want to send the user to any other pages

Comment: @AlexGoaga I bet the page doesnt move at all.. If you want it that way you will need to use AJAX.. It cant be done this way without sending to the other page i.e `update.php`

Comment: @AlexGoaga other page cant respond until it receives something.

Comment: @AlexGoaga this indeed is a poor way to do it.You can simply use your `update.php` script logic in `index.php` & call it on the `Set` button's click.

Comment: @techie_28, i gave up with the ajax code, I made some smaller modification to the initial code. After the user has updated the text in the db, i made in the index.php a code to check if the text inserted is empty or not. if the text is empty, the ajax error appears. Simple...

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use this Index.php file, something like below code,

```
<form method="POST" action="update.php">
    <input type="text" class="main-link" name="link" id="link" value="1" placeholder="Set text new">
    <input type="submit" class="main-link-check" href="#" value="Set">
</form>
```

**updte.php file**

```
<?php echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";

    var str2 = "DEFG";

    if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){

    alert(str2 + " found");

    }

    </script>';
?>
```

Comment: the action you used that is incorrect it shoulld be like `./update.php`

Answer (score 0):

use the below code.To call your php  without page refresh(ajax is included)

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form method="POST" class="sendfm">
<input type="text" class="main-link" name="link" id="link"  placeholder="Set text new">
<input type="submit" class="main-link-check" href="#" value="Set">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).on('submit', '.sendfm', function(){
$.ajax({url: 'update.php', success: function(result){
$('#demo').html(result);

    }});
    return false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

update.php

```js
    <?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    var str2 = "DEFG";
    if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    alert(str2 + " found");
    }
    </script>';
    ?>
```

Comment: this code works good but....the send data text $link = $_POST["link"];
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($link); is not working anymore :(

Comment: In end of the url you should define `link` like :- `update.php?link=something`.                                                                                                                  Don't use `$_POST['link']` use on `$_REQUEST['link']` or `$_GET['link']`

Comment: tried the following : $links = $_GET['link']; and $links = $_REQUEST['link']; followed by $links = mysql_real_escape_string($links); and mysql_query("UPDATE members SET `text`='$links' WHERE `id`='$another_stuff'");

The error is : Notice: "Undefined index: link in..."

Comment: try like this:-     `$links = $_REQUEST['link']
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$real  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $links);                                           $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET text='$real' WHERE id='$another_stuff'");`

Comment: reference link [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp)

Comment: tried also with $links = $_GET['link'] ; it has the same result which gives me the felling that the issue may be in another place? in the script above?

Comment: yes.that code working .Test it my self:  ` <?php $links =$_REQUEST['link']; $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password','dbname'); $real = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $links); $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET text='$real' WHERE id='2'"); echo "updated"; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

hey this is the updated code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'update.php',    
            dataType:'script',
            data: {
                link: $('#link').val(),
            },
            success:function (data) 
            {
                eval(data);
            }          
        });     
    });
});
</script>



<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" class="main-link" name="link" id="link" value="" placeholder="Set text new">
<input type="button" id="submit" class="main-link-check" value="Set" >
</form>


update.php



   echo '<script type="text/javascript">

            var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
            var str2 = "DEFG";
            if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1)
            {
                alert(str2 + " found");
            }

    </script>';exit;
```

Comment: this code displays the script itself ( like a copy paste of an echo into an java error ) not the action resulted from the script ( example found...)

Comment: this cant work if `<input type="submit"` to use ajax it should be `<input type="button"`

Comment: tried the following : $links = $_GET['link']; and $links = $_REQUEST['link']; followed by $links = mysql_real_escape_string($links); and mysql_query("UPDATE members SET text='$links' WHERE id='$another_stuff'"); The error is : Notice: "Undefined index: link in..."

Comment: @AlexGoaga use echo $_POST["link"]; use post method instead  GET

Comment: @AlexGoaga I have edited this answer this may work but above that you do not need other PHP page to do whatever you are doing..you can do it from `index.php` itself in a very simple manner.

Comment: @techie_28, i gave up with the ajax code, I made some smaller modification to the initial code. After the user has updated the text in the db, i made in the index.php a code to check if the text inserted is empty or not. if the text is empty, the ajax error appears. Simple...

Comment: @kirangadhvi I think you need to approve my changes on the answer before they reflect.

Comment: @kirangadhvi, when i add any data to update a database using mysql, the  code generates :  Notice: "Undefined index: link in..."

Comment: where did you get this error?did you get this value in your ajax call?

Comment: @AlexGoaga try it with `data: {'link': $('#link').val()}`.. notice the single quotes around `'link'` in the index.

Comment: just take it as   data: {
                link: $('#link').val(),
            },

Comment: i tried, now the code does not update the db, the error disappeared , and also the ajax error does not appear. I have managed to my request in another way explained earlier in this section of comments " code to check if the text inserted is empty or not. if ..."

Comment: @AlexGoaga your original question never stated that you are updating database.. please use your browser console to monitor(F12 key in Mozilla/Chrome) your AJAX call and take print of the query to see if its getting the params correct as stated by Kiran.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do like this?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" class="main-link" name="link" id="link" value="'.$user_db['values_text'].'" placeholder="Set text new">
    <input type="button" class="main-link-check" id='setBtn' value="Set">
</form>

jQuery('#setBtn').on('click',function(){
  var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
  var str2 = "DEFG";
  if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
   alert(str2 + " found");
  }

});
```

I don't see a point of using `update.php` here?!..